# Image not displayed in markdown file on github page

Tags: github, github-pages

The image is not shown on [my GitHub page](https://psireal9.github.io/lanyon/Trial/) for some reason even though I can view it [locally](https://github.com/psireal9/lanyon/blob/gh-pages/Trial.md).

I have tried multiple ways but can't get it done:(

Comment: Read this: Image paths can break when deploying to gh-pages #1757 https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1757

Comment: hi @NageshSanika i already used relative link `(_images/pic.gif)` but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the relative path to an absolute path in the src of the image.